# errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" when trying to create a foreing key

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables - `Users` and `Points`. In `Points` I want to have the following columns : id, points, user_id(foreign key).

For the purpose I did the below in the following order :

Created I migration looking like this  :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('points', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('points')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');
        });
    }
```

After I ran the migration I got the following error :

> > [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `logos`.`#sql-3da4_79a` (errno: 150
> >     "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed   ") (SQL: alter table
> >     `points` add constraint `points_user_id_foreign` foreign key
> >     (`user_id`) references `user` (`id`))
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General
>   error: 1005 Can't create table `logos`.`#sql-3da4_79a` (errno: 150
>   "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed   ")
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create
>   table `logos`.`#sql-3da4_79a` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is
>   incorrectly formed   ")

Afterwards, I added this relationship to `users`  :

```
 public function points()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Points');
    }
```

And this relationship to `points` :

```
 public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
```

Then I added another migration solely for the foreign key(since the previous migration created the table and its columns despite the error) :

```
   public function up()
{
     Schema::table('points', function (Blueprint $table) {

         $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user');

  });
}
```

After running the migration I got the same error as the first time. I know that the error seems "self explenatory", but honestly it doesn't make any sense to me. I am simply following the official documentation and I don't understand why am I getting this error.

Can somebody explain and help me troubleshoot?

Cheers!

Comment: Please show `users` table migration. Is `users` migrations running before this one?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin users is the standard table that is created when using laravel authentication and it is the first table that was created in the DB

Comment: references on 'users' not 'user' $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

Comment: @LeoinstanceofKelmendi exactly. You should add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of, make sure your timestamp for creating `users` its before you run the `points` migration!

So users should migrate first, before points. Since you want to make sure you have users table already before trying to declare a foregin key!

Then you have a typo on `foreign` statement 
 It should be `users` instead of `user` like below:

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
```